# Same font displayed differently in h1 class

Tags: css, fonts

The ' character is displayed differently in the sidebar and main section on our website. See my test page for the differences: http://www.burkinart.com/test.
The character ' in the name burkin'art at the top of the sidebar is displayed correctly. 
The styling is very simple:

```
h1 {
    font-weight:100;
    font-size: 8em;
    font-family:'Roboto' !important;
}
```

I've tested with different selectors, classes and without any stylesheets but I cannot get the ' character to display correctly in the main section. What am I missing? What is the difference between the sidebar and the main section?

> EDIT: Thanks everyone. I got it to work with `&#39;` ! (but everytime I save the page in WordPress I need to insert the `&#39;` in the title, which is fine for now). I think it has something to do with the character set in the database.

Comment: These quotes are both different, just try to copy the text form the sidebar and paste it in de main section, or use the following code: `&#39;` for a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 2 different characters are being used:

`burkin'art` and `burkin’art`

This has nothing to do with your CSS. You need to change all of them to one type of quote so that they all appear the same.

Comment: Thank you, see my comment on Andrusch. The problems seems to be within WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

You're using a different accent in the main section!

Your're writing

> burkin'art

in the sidebar, but

> burkin’art

in the main section. I just copy pasted the code from what Chrome inspector showed me at your link http://burkinart.com/test/

Write the content again using the same **'** character.

Comment: Could it be that simple?! :) I've tried it but it doesn't work. Now I see the difference, one is directly from a php file and the other is written within WordPress.. Does WP do something else with the character?

Comment: :) .. sometimes solutions to big problems are indeed that simple.. Which accent are you adding? Are you editing the main content in WP or the sidebar? Where does the php file come from? You could change the accent there if you have access to it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the wrong character being used, use the following HTML to solve the problem.

```
<a class="sidebar-brand" href="index.php">burkin'art</a>


<a href="http://burkinart.com/test/" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to burkin’art">burkin'art</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick review of your code on page revealed a difference in the apostrophe or  '  used.

Your code shows a burkin’art vs the plain text **burkin'art**.

The apostrophe used is acting like a special character from a custom font.

Try one quick remedy - **type** out the burkin'art on any text editor like Notepad, copy and paste the same in your code and try again. When I inspected the element in FF and edited the apostrophe, it seemed to fix the issue - ONLY for the text in the `<H1>` tag. (see screenshot)[image]

Comment: Thank you, see my comment on Andrusch. The problems seems to be within WordPress?

Comment: Could be the encoding text when you enter content in the CMS... Always use the simple text editor in WP  rather than the default 'Word' editor interface, character encoding is solid then

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone. I got it to work with `&#39;` !
(but everytime I save the page in WordPress I need to insert the `&#39;` in the title, which is fine for now).
I think it has something to do with the character set in the database.